# Idiomatic callbacks in Rust

Tags: callback, rust

In C/C++ I'd normally do callbacks with a plain function pointer, maybe passing a `void* userdata` parameter too. Something like this:

```cpp
typedef void (*Callback)();

class Processor
{
public:
    void setCallback(Callback c)
    {
        mCallback = c;
    }
    
    void processEvents()
    {
        //...
        mCallback();
    }
private:
    Callback mCallback;
};
```

What is the idiomatic way of doing this in Rust? Specifically, what types should my `setCallback()` function take, and what type should `mCallback` be? Should it take an `Fn`? Maybe `FnMut`? Do I save it `Boxed`? An example would be amazing.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Short answer: For maximum flexibility, you can store the callback as a boxed `FnMut` object, with the callback setter generic on callback type. The code for this is shown in the last example in the answer. For a more detailed explanation, read on.

#### "Function pointers": callbacks as `fn`

The closest equivalent of the C++ code in the question would be declaring callback as a `fn` type. `fn` encapsulates functions defined by the `fn` keyword, much like C++'s function pointers:

```
type Callback = fn();

struct Processor {
    callback: Callback,
}

impl Processor {
    fn set_callback(&mut self, c: Callback) {
        self.callback = c;
    }

    fn process_events(&self) {
        (self.callback)();
    }
}

fn simple_callback() {
    println!("hello world!");
}

fn main() {
    let p = Processor {
        callback: simple_callback,
    };
    p.process_events(); // hello world!
}
```

This code could be extended to include an `Option<Box<Any>>` to hold the "user data" associated with the function. Even so, it would not be idiomatic Rust. The Rust way to associate data with a function is to capture it in an anonymous *closure*, just like in modern C++. Since closures are not `fn`, `set_callback` will need to accept other kinds of function objects.

#### Callbacks as generic function objects

In both Rust and C++ closures with the same call signature come in different sizes to accommodate the different values they might capture. Additionally, each closure definition generates a unique anonymous type for the closure's value. Due to these constraints, the struct cannot name the type of its `callback` field, nor can it use an alias.

One way to embed a closure in the struct field without referring to a concrete type is by making the struct *generic*. The struct will automatically adapt its size and the type of callback for the concrete function or closure you pass to it:

```
struct Processor<CB> {
    callback: CB,
}

impl<CB> Processor<CB>
where
    CB: FnMut(),
{
    fn set_callback(&mut self, c: CB) {
        self.callback = c;
    }

    fn process_events(&mut self) {
        (self.callback)();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "world!".to_string();
    let callback = || println!("hello {}", s);
    let mut p = Processor { callback };
    p.process_events();
}
```

As before, `set_callback()` will accept functions defined with `fn`, but this one will also accept closures as `|| println!("hello world!")`, as well as closures that capture values, such as `|| println!("{}", somevar)`. Because of this the processor doesn't need `userdata` to accompany the callback; the closure provided by the caller of `set_callback` will automatically capture the data it needs from its environment and have it available when invoked.

But what's the deal with the `FnMut`, why not just `Fn`? Since closures hold captured values, Rust's usual mutation rules must apply when calling the closure. Depending on what the closures do with the values they hold, they are grouped in three families, each marked with a trait:

- `Fn` are closures that only read data, and may be safely called multiple times, possibly from multiple threads. Both above closures are `Fn`.
- `FnMut` are closures that modify data, e.g. by writing to a captured `mut` variable. They may also be called multiple times, but not in parallel. (Calling a `FnMut` closure from multiple threads would lead to a data race, so it can only be done with the protection of a mutex.) The closure object must be declared mutable by the caller.
- `FnOnce` are closures that *consume* some of the data they capture, e.g. by passing a captured value to a function that takes it by value. As the name implies, these may be called only once, and the caller must own them.

Somewhat counter-intuitively, when specifying a trait bound for the type of an object that accepts a closure, `FnOnce` is actually the most permissive one. Declaring that a generic callback type must satisfy the `FnOnce` trait means that it will accept literally any closure. But that comes with a price: it means the holder is only allowed to call it once. Since `process_events()` may opt to invoke the callback multiple times, and as the method itself may be called more than once, the next most permissive bound is `FnMut`. Note that we had to mark `process_events` as mutating `self`.

#### Non-generic callbacks: function trait objects

Even though the generic implementation of the callback is extremely efficient, it has serious interface limitations. It requires each `Processor` instance to be parameterized with a concrete callback type, which means that a single `Processor` can only deal with a single callback type. Given that each closure has a distinct type, the generic `Processor` cannot handle `proc.set_callback(|| println!("hello"))` followed by `proc.set_callback(|| println!("world"))`.  Extending the struct to support two callbacks fields would require the whole struct to be parameterized to two types, which would quickly become unwieldy as the number of callbacks grows. Adding more type parameters wouldn't work if the number of callbacks needed to be dynamic, e.g. to implement an `add_callback` function that maintains a vector of different callbacks.

To remove the type parameter, we can take advantage of [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html), the feature of Rust that allows automatic creation of dynamic interfaces based on traits. This is sometimes referred to as *type erasure* and is a popular technique in C++[[1]](http://davekilian.com/cpp-type-erasure.html)[[2]](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/type-erasure-part-i/), not to be confused with Java and FP languages' somewhat different use of the term. Readers familiar with C++ will recognize the distinction between a closure that implements `Fn` and an `Fn` trait object as equivalent to the distinction between general function objects and `std::function` values in C++.

A trait object is created by borrowing an object with the `&` operator and casting or coercing it to a reference to the specific trait. In this case, since `Processor` needs to own the callback object, we cannot use borrowing, but must store the callback in a heap-allocated `Box<dyn Trait>` (the Rust equivalent of `std::unique_ptr`), which is functionally equivalent to a trait object.

If `Processor` stores `Box<dyn FnMut()>`, it no longer needs to be generic, but the `set_callback` *method* now accepts a generic `c` via an [`impl Trait` argument](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/impl-trait-for-returning-complex-types-with-ease.html). As such, it can accept any kind of callable, including closures with state, and properly box it before storing it in the `Processor`. The generic argument to `set_callback` doesn't limit what kind of callback the processor accepts, as the type of the accepted callback is decoupled from the type stored in the `Processor` struct.

```rust
struct Processor {
    callback: Box<dyn FnMut()>,
}

impl Processor {
    fn set_callback(&mut self, c: impl FnMut() + 'static) {
        self.callback = Box::new(c);
    }

    fn process_events(&mut self) {
        (self.callback)();
    }
}

fn simple_callback() {
    println!("hello");
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = Processor {
        callback: Box::new(simple_callback),
    };
    p.process_events();
    let s = "world!".to_string();
    let callback2 = move || println!("hello {}", s);
    p.set_callback(callback2);
    p.process_events();
}
```

#### Lifetime of references inside boxed closures

The `'static` lifetime bound on the type of the `c` argument accepted by `set_callback` is a simple way to convince the compiler that *references* contained in `c`, which might be a closure that refers to its environment, only refer to global values and will therefore remain valid throughout the use of the callback. But the static bound is also very heavy-handed: while it accepts closures that own objects just fine (which we've ensured above by making the closure `move`), it rejects closures that refer to local environment, even when they only refer to values that outlive the processor and would in fact be safe.

As we only need the callbacks alive as long as the processor is alive, we should try to tie their lifetime to that of the processor, which is a less strict bound than `'static`. But if we just remove the `'static` lifetime bound from `set_callback`, it no longer compiles. This is because `set_callback` creates a new box and assigns it to the `callback` field defined as `Box<dyn FnMut()>`. Since the definition doesn't specify a lifetime for the boxed trait object, `'static` is implied, and the assignment would effectively widen the lifetime (from an unnamed arbitrary lifetime of the callback to `'static`), which is disallowed. The fix is to provide an explicit lifetime for the processor and tie that lifetime to both the references in the box and the references in the callback received by `set_callback`:

```rust
struct Processor<'a> {
    callback: Box<dyn FnMut() + 'a>,
}

impl<'a> Processor<'a> {
    fn set_callback(&mut self, c: impl FnMut() + 'a) {
        self.callback = Box::new(c);
    }
    // ...
}
```

With these lifetimes being made explicit, it is no longer necessary to use `'static`. The closure can now refer to the local `s` object, i.e. no longer has to be `move`, provided that the definition of `s` is placed before the definition of `p` to ensure that the string outlives the processor.

Comment: Wow, I think this is the best answer I've ever got to a SO question! Thank you! Perfectly explained. One minor thing I don't get though - why does `CB` have to be `'static` in the final example?

Comment: The `Box<FnMut()>` used in the struct field means `Box<FnMut() + 'static>`. Roughly "The boxed trait object contains no references / any references it contains outlive (or equal) `'static`". It prevents the callback from capturing locals by reference.

Comment: Ah I see, I think!

Comment: You should probably mention the upsides of genericity - namely the lack of indirection, both for data and for resolving the call.

Comment: @Veedrac The trouble is that for this type of use case those aren't really upsides, especially the lack of indirection. The OP asked for an idiomatic way to express "function pointers" (with *userdata*, even).

Comment: @Timmmm More details on the `'static` bound in a [separate blog post](https://morestina.net/blog/793/closure-lifetimes-in-rust).

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thank you for providing it @user4815162342.

Comment: You don't provide an example of a baxed trait, you just give an example of a boxed Fn with little explanation.  What are the pros and cons of boxed trait VS boxed Fn?

Comment: @MikeMestnik I'm not sure what kind of example of a boxed trait you're looking for, but `Fn` is a trait and the last example stores it boxed to allow polymorphism.

Comment: True.  This probably needs to be in the textbooks.

Comment: And what if you want to parse a member function from a particular struct? Is this possible in Rust, or are we forced to use global scoped functions and closures?

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to deal with lifetime and cannot afford the heap allocation, then here is an implementation that uses reference to implement the callback:

```
use core::ffi::c_void;
use core::mem::transmute;
use core::ptr::null_mut;
use core::marker::PhantomData;

/// ErasedFnPointer can either points to a free function or associated one that
/// `&mut self`
struct ErasedFnPointer<'a, T, Ret> {
    struct_pointer: *mut c_void,
    fp: *const (),
    // The `phantom_*` field is used so that the compiler won't complain about
    // unused generic parameter.
    phantom_sp: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
    phantom_fp: PhantomData<fn(T) -> Ret>,
}

impl<'a, T, Ret> Copy for ErasedFnPointer<'a, T, Ret> {}
impl<'a, T, Ret> Clone for ErasedFnPointer<'a, T, Ret> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        *self
    }
}

impl<'a, T, Ret> ErasedFnPointer<'a, T, Ret> {
    pub fn from_associated<S>(struct_pointer: &'a mut S, fp: fn(&mut S, T) -> Ret)
        -> ErasedFnPointer<'a, T, Ret>
    {
        ErasedFnPointer {
            struct_pointer: struct_pointer as *mut _ as *mut c_void,
            fp: fp as *const (),
            phantom_sp: PhantomData,
            phantom_fp: PhantomData,
        }
    }
    
    pub fn from_free(fp: fn(T) -> Ret) -> ErasedFnPointer<'static, T, Ret> {
        ErasedFnPointer {
            struct_pointer: null_mut(),
            fp: fp as *const (),
            phantom_sp: PhantomData,
            phantom_fp: PhantomData,
        }
    }
    
    pub fn call(&self, param: T) -> Ret {
        if self.struct_pointer.is_null() {
            let fp = unsafe { transmute::<_, fn(T) -> Ret>(self.fp) };
            fp(param)
        } else {
            let fp = unsafe { transmute::<_, fn(*mut c_void, T) -> Ret>(self.fp) };
            fp(self.struct_pointer, param)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let erased_ptr = ErasedFnPointer::from_free(|x| {
        println!("Hello, {}", x);
        x
    });
    erased_ptr.call(2333);
    
    println!("size_of_val(erased_ptr) = {}", core::mem::size_of_val(&erased_ptr));

    ErasedFnPointer::from_associated(
        &mut Test { x: 1},
        Test::f
    ).call(1);
    
    let mut x = None;
    ErasedFnPointer::from_associated(&mut x, |x, param| {
        *x = Some(param);
        println!("{:#?}", x);
    }).call(1);
}

struct Test {
    x: i32
}
impl Test {
    fn f(&mut self, y: i32) -> i32 {
        let z = self.x + y;
        println!("Hello from Test, {}", z);
        z
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the type of scenario where a callback is used, you should consider the Promise alternative.
It is much easier to use than callbacks because it avoids nesting (*callback hell*).

Consider this:

```
fn main() {
    let fut = do_async(&Calculation{ value: 12 });

    let resp = fut().unwrap(); // call fut() to wait for the respbnse

    println!("{}", resp);
}
```

For any calculation:

- you define an struct whose fields are its inputs (name is not important).
- you implement the `Runner` trait:

  - you choose what to return
  - you write the code of `run()`, which will be exected by a separate thread

```
struct Calculation {  // <---- choose: name
    value: i32  // <----- choose: inputs for your async work
}

impl Runner for Calculation {
    type ReturnType = i32;  // <--- choose: calculation return type

    fn run(&self) -> Option<Self::ReturnType> {  // <-- implement: code executed by a thread
        println!("async calculation starts");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3000));

        return Some(self.value * 2);
    }
}
```

Finaly, this is the "magic":

```
trait Runner: Send + Sync {
    type ReturnType: Send; // associated type

    fn run(&self) -> Option<Self::ReturnType>;
}

fn do_async<TIn: Runner>(f: &'static TIn) -> impl FnOnce()-> Option<TIn::ReturnType> {
    let (sender, receiver) = channel::<Option<TIn::ReturnType>>();

    let hand = thread::spawn(move || {
        sender.send(f.run()).unwrap(); 
    });

    let f = move || -> Option<TIn::ReturnType> {
        let res = receiver.recv().unwrap();
        hand.join().unwrap();
        return res;
    };

    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/70943671/286335 just for closures.

```
fn main() {
    let n = 2;

    let fut = do_async(move || {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3000));
        return n * 1234;
    });

    let resp = fut(); // call fut() to wait for the response

    println!("{}", resp);
} // ()
```

where `do_async` is

```
fn do_async<TOut, TFun>(foo: TFun) -> (impl FnOnce() -> TOut)
 where
    TOut: Send + Sync + 'static,
    TFun: FnOnce() -> TOut + Send + Sync + 'static,
{
    let (sender, receiver) = channel::<TOut>();

    let hand = thread::spawn(move || {
        sender.send(foo()).unwrap(); 
    });

    let f = move || -> TOut {
        let res = receiver.recv().unwrap();
        hand.join().unwrap();
        return res;
    };

    return f;
} // ()
```