# Convenient 'Option<Box<Any>>' access when success is assured?

Tags: rust, any

When writing callbacks for generic interfaces, it can be useful for them to define their own local data which they are responsible for creating and accessing.

In C I would just use a void pointer, *C-like example*:

```
struct SomeTool {
    int type;
    void *custom_data;
};

void invoke(SomeTool *tool) {
    StructOnlyForThisTool *data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
    /* ... fill in the data ... */
    tool.custom_data = custom_data;
}
void execute(SomeTool *tool) {
    StructOnlyForThisTool *data = tool.custom_data;
    if (data.foo_bar) { /* do something */ }
}
```

When writing something similar in Rust, replacing `void *` with `Option<Box<Any>>`, however I'm finding that accessing the data is **unreasonably verbose**, eg:

```
struct SomeTool {
    type: i32,
    custom_data: Option<Box<Any>>,
};

fn invoke(tool: &mut SomeTool) {
    let data = StructOnlyForThisTool { /* my custom data */ }
    /* ... fill in the data ... */
    tool.custom_data = Some(Box::new(custom_data));
}
fn execute(tool: &mut SomeTool) {
    let data = tool.custom_data.as_ref().unwrap().downcast_ref::<StructOnlyForThisTool>().unwrap();
    if data.foo_bar { /* do something */ }
}
```

There is one line here which I'd like to be able to write in a more compact way:

- `tool.custom_data.as_ref().unwrap().downcast_ref::<StructOnlyForThisTool>().unwrap()`
- `tool.custom_data.as_ref().unwrap().downcast_mut::<StructOnlyForThisTool>().unwrap()`

While each method makes sense on its own, in practice it's not something I'd want to write throughout a code-base, and not something I'm going to want to type out often or remember easily.

By convention, the uses of unwrap here aren't dangerous because:

- While only some tools define custom data, the ones that do always define it.
- When the data is set, by convention the tool only ever sets its own data. So there is no chance of having the wrong data.
- Any time these conventions aren't followed, its a bug and should panic.

Given these conventions, and assuming accessing custom-data from a tool is something that's done often - what would be a good way to simplify this expression?

---

Some possible options:

- Remove the `Option`, just use `Box<Any>` with `Box::new(())` representing `None` so access can be simplified a little.
- Use a macro or function to hide verbosity - passing in the `Option<Box<Any>>`: *will work of course, but prefer not - would use as a last resort.*
- Add a trait to `Option<Box<Any>>` which exposes a method such as `tool.custom_data.unwrap_box::<StructOnlyForThisTool>()` with matching `unwrap_box_mut`.

---

Update 1): since asking this question a point I didn't include seems relevant.
There may be multiple callback functions like `execute` which must all be able to access the `custom_data`. At the time I didn't think this was important to point out.

Update 2): Wrapping this in a function which takes `tool` isn't practical, since the borrow checker then prevents further access to members of `tool` until the cast variable goes out of scope, I found the only reliable way to do this was to write a macro.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use closures? Closures are there to stop us from needing a function-pointer + data-pointer pair. Just like slices are there to stop us from needing a data-pointer + length pair.

Comment: How about creating accessor methods for `SomeTool`? `custom_data()` and `custom_data_mut()`.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña: Same reaction here; I wonder if we're missing something because it seems obvious that one should create a function rather than copy/paste :(

Comment: Having a function makes some sense of course, coming from C however, does this mean you would have to define some new function every time you wanted to have a type with this style of access? - or would you write this as a generic function which takes the `Option<Box<Any>>` as an argument? eg: `some_box_any_unwrap_as::<StructOnlyForThisTool>(&tool.custom_data)`. While I could write a macro or function which *works*, they feel a little awkward - especially if this is an API for others to use.

Answer (score 1):

If the implementation really only has a single method with a name like `execute`, that is a strong indication to consider using a closure to capture the implementation data. `SomeTool` can incorporate an arbitrary callable in a type-erased manner using a boxed `FnMut`, as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41081702/1600898). `execute()` then boils down to invoking the closure stored in the struct field implementation closure using `(self.impl_)()`. For a more general approach, that will also work when you have more methods on the implementation, read on.

An idiomatic and type-safe equivalent of the type+dataptr C pattern is to store the implementation type and pointer to data together as a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/trait-objects.html). The `SomeTool` struct can contain a single field, a boxed `SomeToolImpl` trait object, where the trait specifies tool-specific methods such as `execute`. This has the following characteristics:

- You no longer need an explicit `type` field because the run-time type information is incorporated in the trait object.
- Each tool's implementation of the trait methods can access its own data in a type-safe manner without casts or unwraps. This is because the trait object's vtable automatically invokes the correct function for the correct trait implementation, and it is a compile-time error to try to invoke a different one.
- The "fat pointer" representation of the trait object has the same performance characteristics as the type+dataptr pair - for example, the size of `SomeTool` will be two pointers, and accessing the implementation data will still involve a single pointer dereference.

Here is an example implementation:

```
struct SomeTool {
    impl_: Box<SomeToolImpl>,
}

impl SomeTool {
    fn execute(&mut self) {
        self.impl_.execute();
    }
}

trait SomeToolImpl {
    fn execute(&mut self);
}

struct SpecificTool1 {
    foo_bar: bool
}

impl SpecificTool1 {
    pub fn new(foo_bar: bool) -> SomeTool {
        let my_data = SpecificTool1 { foo_bar: foo_bar };
        SomeTool { impl_: Box::new(my_data) }
    }
}

impl SomeToolImpl for SpecificTool1 {
    fn execute(&mut self) {
        println!("I am {}", self.foo_bar);
    }
}

struct SpecificTool2 {
    num: u64
}

impl SpecificTool2 {
    pub fn new(num: u64) -> SomeTool {
        let my_data = SpecificTool2 { num: num };
        SomeTool { impl_: Box::new(my_data) }
    }
}

impl SomeToolImpl for SpecificTool2 {
    fn execute(&mut self) {
        println!("I am {}", self.num);
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut tool1: SomeTool = SpecificTool1::new(true);
    let mut tool2: SomeTool = SpecificTool2::new(42);
    tool1.execute();
    tool2.execute();
}
```

Note that, in this design, it doesn't make sense to make implementation an `Option` because we always associate the tool *type* with the implementation. While it is perfectly valid to have an implementation without data, it must always have a type associated with it.

Comment: Does this work when there are multiple methods like `execute` needed?

Comment: @ideasman42 It does. In fact, that is kind of the whole point of bothering with defining a trait; otherwise a simple `FnMut` would suffice. Try it, the [example is compilable](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=976b179960d0322f5811af1825648f3f&version=stable&backtrace=0).