# generic callback with data

Tags: events, rust, callback

There is already a very [popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081240/idiomatic-callbacks-in-rust) about this topic but I don;t fully understand the answer.

The goal is:

I need a list (read a Vec) of "function pointers" that modify data stored elsewhere in a program. The simplest example I can come up with are callbacks to be called when a key is pressed. So when any key is pressed, all functions passed to the object will be called in some order.

Reading the answer, it is not clear to me how I would be able to make such a list. It sounds like I would need to restrict the type of the callback to something known, else I don't know how you would be able to make an array of it.

It's also not clear to me how to store the data pointers/references.

Say I have

```rust
struct Processor<CB>
where
    CB: FnMut(),
{
    callback: CB,
}
```

Like the answer suggests, I can't make an array of processors, can I? since each Processor is technically a different type depending on the generic isntantiation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, you can't make a vector of processors. Usually, closures all have different, innominable types. What you want instead are trait objects, which allow you to have dynamic dispatch of callback calls. Since those are not `Sized`, you'd probably want to put them in a `Box`. The final type is `Vec<Box<dyn FnMut()>>`.

```rust
fn add_callback(list: &mut Vec<Box<dyn FnMut()>>, cb: impl FnMut() + 'static) {
    list.push(Box::new(cb))
}

fn run_callback(list: &mut [Box<dyn FnMut()>]) {
    for cb in list {
        cb()
    }
}
```

see the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d664c40eeafa6a72a7492e325a39632c)

---

If you do like that, however, you might have some issues with the lifetimes (because your either force to move-in everything, or only modify values that life for `'static`, which isn't very convenient. Instead, the following might be better

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct Producer<'a> {
    list: Vec<Box<dyn FnMut() + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Producer<'a> {
    fn add_callback(&mut self, cb: impl FnMut() + 'a) {
        self.list.push(Box::new(cb))
    }
    
    fn run_callbacks(&mut self) {
        for cb in &mut self.list {
            cb()
        }
    }
}

fn callback_1() {
    println!("Hello!");
}

fn main() {
    let mut modified = 0;
    let mut prod = Producer::default();
    prod.add_callback(callback_1);
    prod.add_callback(
        || {
            modified += 1;
            println!("World!");
        }
    );
    prod.run_callbacks();
    drop(prod);
    println!("{}", modified);
}
```

see the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9ace9046e06bffa2be0945797471fdc2)

Just a few things to note:

1. You manually have to `drop` the producer, otherwise Rust will complain that it will be dropped at the end of the scope, but it contains (through the closure) an exclusive reference to `modified`, which is not ok since I try to read it.
2. Current, `run_callbacks` take a `&mut self`, because we only require for a `FnMut`. If you wanted it to be only a `&self`, you'd need to replace `FnMut` with `Fn`, which means the callbacks can still modify things *outside* of them, but not *inside*.

Comment: Just for completeness, how would you call these objects ina  loop?

Comment: @Makogan I added an example of that too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all closures are differents type, so if you want to have a vec of different closure you will need to make them trait objects. This can be archieve with `Box<dyn Trait>` (or any smart pointer). `Box<dyn FnMut()>` implements `FnMut()`, so you can have `Processor<Box<dyn FnMut()>>` and can make a vec of them, and call the callbacks on them: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d1f7493f9c76d8574b8e27ba083bad7)